# List comprehension for dictionary – condition for adding key if value is not null

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

Having list comprehension of dictionaries. My goal is to create dictionary with one key if `key["formula"]` does not exist or dictionary with two keys if formula exists.

Currently having something like this and it works

```
cols = [{"header":k, **(({"formula":v["formula"]}) if v.get("formula") else {})} for k,v in inp["cols"].items()]
```

Is there any shorter / more elegant way to gain the same effect?

Edit (expected output): for clarification, what I need to achieve is

```
inp = {"cols":{"header1":{"formula":"test"}}}
cols = [{"header":k, **(({"formula":v["formula"]}) if v.get("formula") else {})} for k,v in inp["cols"].items()] 
-> 
[{'header': 'header1', 'formula': 'test'}]


inp = {"cols":{"header1":{"notformula":"test"}}}
cols = [{"header":k, **(({"formula":v["formula"]}) if v.get("formula") else {})} for k,v in inp["cols"].items()]
->
[{'header': 'header1'}]
```

Comment: "Shorter" and "more elegant" are, in many cases and certainly in this one, mutually exclusive. I have no idea what your code is doing, and if you had written it on two or three lines, I probably would be able to tell at a glance.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo so the above code ain't that bad in terms of readibility? It does nothing special -> Creates new dictionary based on another one with multiple keys.

Comment: That's what the if is typically for. Just don't give it an else. if 'formula' in v (I would post code, but I can't reproduce from your code)

Comment: @KennyOstrom Not sure what u mean? Removal of else in this particular expression will raise an error.

Comment: @KennyOstrom edited and added expected output

Comment: The "if" syntax only works in the comprehension's loop, which is higher level than you need. My bad. Since you're working with fixed keys in fixed positions, I'd just use those, although you can hide that inside a make_summary(name, data) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve it slightly using the dict union operator introduced in Python 3.9. Here it is with extra line breaks for readability and PEP 8 compliance.

```py
cols = [
    {"header": k} | ({"formula": v["formula"]} if "formula" in v else {})
    for k, v in inp["cols"].items()
]
```

I've also replaced your `v.get("formula")` with an `in` check. `v.get("formula")` is falsy if `v` is `{"formula": []}`, for instance, which you may, but probably don't, want.

I would consider extracting the logic on the second line into a function.

Comment: Im limited to 3.6 that's why used ** :P Thanks anyway, I will have to consider the function for that.